# Does h.264/ffmpeg do the inter and intra prediction per channel or per macroblock(3 channels together)

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I.e.

Could each color(YUV) channel in one macroblock be predicted to different marcoblock?

Answer (score 0):

Inter prediction (motion vectors) in H.264 standard is same for all planes of macroblock i.e. no.

Intra prediction can be different for luma and chroma (same for U and V) but only for 4:2:0 and 4:2:2 chroma formats.

For 4:4:4 chroma format there is separate_colour_plane_flag which can say that all 3 planes are independent monochrome planes encoded separately (i.e. in different slice NALs) with fully independent prediction and other decisions. But at least libx264 doesn't support this mode so there predictions are same for all planes for 4:4:4.